# MS-Access : SQL JOIN and INSERT INTO with WHERE slow

Tags: performance, ms-access, join, sql-insert

Long story short:

A SELECT query with an INNER JOIN of two tables is inserted into a new table via INSERT INTO. While this query finishes within 20 seconds, adding a WHERE condition in the SELECT part freezes the query!

---

DETAILS:

I have two tables (i=1,2)

```
Table i : Tab_i

ID_i (Long, Indexed, Duplicates possible)
MyDate (Date)
Field_1 (...)
...
Field_N (...)
```

I created a Table Tab_MATCH to store matching IDs when comparing the two tables

```
Table Tab_MATCH
ID_1 (Long, Indexed, Duplicates possible)
ID_2 (Long, Indexed, Duplicates possible)
```

The matching is done via a join of the two tables Tab_1 and Tab_2, inserting the matching IDs into Table Tab_MATCH

```
INSERT INTO 
  Tab_MATCH
SELECT
  Tab_1.ID_1, 
  Tab_2.ID_2,
FROM 
  Tab_1 
INNER JOIN 
  Tab_2 
ON
  (Tab_1.Field_1 = Tab_2.Field_1) AND
  (...) AND
  (Tab_1.Field_N = Tab_2.Field_N)
```

This procedure runs fine within about 20 Seconds.
I then want to add a constraint on the Date of Tab_2, e.g. considering only entries before the 1st of march 2014 (3/1/2014), so I added

```
INSERT INTO 
  Tab_MATCH
SELECT
  Tab_1.ID_1, 
  Tab_2.ID_2,
FROM 
  Tab_1 
INNER JOIN 
  Tab_2 
ON
  (Tab_1.Field_1 = Tab_2.Field_1) AND
  (...) AND
  (Tab_1.Field_N = Tab_2.Field_N)
WHERE 
  Tab_2.MyDate < #3/1/2014#
```

This query now runs FOREVER. If I only do the select with date constraint, it also finishes within about 20 seconds, but the insert kind of freezes!

What am I missing here? Is there any table scan involved for each join entry with this procedure or anything else? (Using MS Access 2016 (32-Bit))

Comment: The misteries of MS-Access. It's hard to debug that kind of things because Access doesnt have an EXPLAIN PLAN mechanism. Have you tried to compact/repair your database?

Comment: Yes its a pain... I already compacted/repaired (several times) and also tried to add the WHERE clause in the join directly `... INNER JOIN 
(SELECT * FROM Tab_2 WHERE Tab_2.MyDate < #3/1/2014#) ...` but no improvements...

Comment: I just tried to do the insert via a VBA loop over the SELECT query as a DAO.Recordset (yes I am at this point already...) and also here it freezes when only calculation the number of entries `Dim rs as DAO.Recordset; set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT..."); rs.MoveFirst; rs.MoveLast; Debug.Print rs.RecordCount; rs.Close` The `rs.MoveLast` command again freezes... Dropping the WHERE clause also works fine...

Comment: Make a temp table that's your best option. Do an INSERT without WHERE clause but with columns `ID_1`, `ID_2` and `mydate` . Then either DELETE all records not matching the date, or INSERT into another table with your WHERE clause. If you see what I mean otherwise I write a proper answer

Comment: Well yes this might help, but as always the problem is embedded in a larger context, doing multiple comparisons on multiple tables. I will test this procedure. But in general I would like to understand the difference between the SELECT with and without the INSERT here, and which role the WHERE clause is playing, and WHY it is freezing the `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ... INNERJOIN ... WHERE... ` query, which is not a very exotic but rather standard task...

Answer (score 0):

Create and save a query like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM Tab_2 
WHERE MyDate < #3/1/2014#
```

Then replace Tab_2 in your original query with this saved query.

Comment: The code posted is just an example and of course embedded in a more complex context. This means the WHERE clause is dynamic and needs to be applied with different conditions. I have a VBA script running several comparisons after another on multiple tables, working fine. So I would like to use the ORIGINAL tables (I will be limited by the 2GB file size limit on *.accdb files) instead of creating a tmp table for each comparison. As stated in the other comment above, I would like to understand the influence of the WHERE clause on the query...

Comment: I just tried your approach and it didn't improve the query speed, i.e. also freezes. I also don't see the difference between an external query or adding the exact code inside my query. Can you comment why you would expect a difference?

Comment: It forces Access to filter Tab_2 before attempting any join, thus much less data to compare. An old trick really. If that freezes, something else is going on, I guess; it cannot be the criteria that freezes Access.